# Can't build app on latest android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, build, proguard

Has anyone experienced building apps from 3.0.1 and it won't run?

I think this guy here encountered the same issue as mine;
[Unable to Build Release Apk Android Studio 3.0.1 Proguard-Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792492/unable-to-build-release-apk-android-studio-3-0-1-proguard-rules)

My app also has ** (tried to apply solution as suggested above) on my proguard rules and I can't remove them as this would cause the app to not build.

PLEASE HELP ME

## UPDATE 2

outcomesound's **SOLUTION WORKED FOR ME** see his answer below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809116/4767606

## UPDATE 1

I was able to apply Wahdat Kashmiri's answer below; debug version runs fine but when switching the build for release, the app only runs until splash screen and then it crashes.

```
implementation  fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1') {
   transitive = true;
}
implementation ('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
   exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
   transitive = true;
}
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
   exclude module: "httpclient"
}
implementation('com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.+') {
   exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.9'
implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.3-android'
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.9.1'
implementation 'ly.count.android:sdk:16.06.04'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.1'
implementation 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.rollbar:rollbar-android:0.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
```

Comment: I think any logs would be fine too ...

Comment: Can you share error log

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. Job failed, see logs for details

I receive this error when building the app

Comment: Do you want to build with  "minifyEnabled true"?

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan yes I want to build with minifyEnabled as I'd want to obfuscate my code :D

Comment: Then, I need to see your library list that you have used.

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan was able to update post with libraries used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I was able to fix my problem by adding a missing proguard rule for jsoup. It was strange because before I did not need to add it. Check your libraries maybe you need to add a new rule.

Comment: OH MY GOSH YOU SAVED MY A** TODAY!!! THIS WORKED FOR ME!!! THANKS A TON!!!

Answer (score 1):

Build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.techno.giants.json"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Build.gradle roject

```
 buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: thanks, will try your suggested

compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: debug works but release version runs 'til splash screen only

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem a few weeks later. I solved this problem by adding this proguard rules:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
} 
-ignorewarnings
```

And make sure you replace all compile by implementation & all testCompile by testImplementation.